How to say Onwards to the stars in Latin?
I just want the appropriate onwards to use when saying this to a friend. Would porro be correct? I want to use ad astra for to the stars.

Good question. Porro sounds good, and there is the attestation Porro, Quirites! (Onward, ye Romans!), but other than that it seems to be rarely used for actual movement somewhere. Instead, lots and lots of perge porro in the comedians, which just means “go on …” Protinus might be another good candidate.
